# why my skybox disappeared after I added the urp package?

Tags: unity-game-engine, rendering, skybox, urp

I want to add light2d to my project, but it's a decision I made after months I started the project, so then I added the urp package.
But something strange happended: my skybox disappeared. I mean, it can't display neither in my scene view nor game view, it seems it's totally transparented instead of a material error.
I have checked my lighting settings and camera settings, but there's no problem.
I tried to restart Unity editor, but it can't solve the problem.

Sorry for poor English, hoping you can read this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a "URP Asset (with 2D Renderer)", it wont use the Skybox material set in Lightning -> Environment.
Its probably by design i guess (2D dont need a "box", instead a rect will suffice).

Use the other Asset (with Universal Renderer) or set your "Skybox" as Sprite material in the scene.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm using the "URP Asset (with 2D Renderer)", maybe it's why. I'll try other ways you suggested, thank you!